# Angular error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Tags: angular, angular-material

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/dialog.d.ts:142:22 -
> error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could
> not be resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> This likely means that the library (@angular/material/dialog) which
> declares MatDialog has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not
> compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library
> is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the
> library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible
> with Ivy.
>
> 142 export declare class MatDialog extends
> _MatDialogBase {

I already tried :

- update/reinstall --> no effect
- restart the server/ empty cache --> no effect
- Disable Ivy --> other error
- Disable aoc --> no errors but white page
- "postinstall": "ngcc" --> no effect
- Ran as sudo --> no effect

Please help me I tried many things and i'm deseperate

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

// Firebase imports
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
//import { SearchBarComponent } from './shared/navbar/search-bar/search-bar.component';
import { AngularFireAuthGuard } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
import { NewCommentComponent } from './comments/new-comment/new-comment.component';
import { NewDocumentComponent } from './documents/new-document/new-document.component';
import { QuestionComponent } from './documents/question/question.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SingleDocumentComponent } from './documents/single-document/single-document.component';
import { EditDocumentComponent } from './documents/edit-document/edit-document.component';
import { TemplateComponent } from './documents/template/template.component';

import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AngularFireFunctions, FUNCTIONS_REGION } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { EditorModule } from '@tinymce/tinymce-angular';

import { CategoryDialogComponent } from './home-page/category-dialog/category-dialog.component';
import { DocumentCheckoutComponent } from './documents/document-checkout/document-checkout.component';

import { CarouselComponent } from './home-page/carousel/carousel.component';
import { ProPageComponent } from './pro-page/pro-page.component';
import { MarkdownEditorModule } from './markdown-editor/markdown-editor.module';
import { MarkdownEditorOptions } from './markdown-editor/markdownEditorOptions';
// import { CheckoutComponent } from './checkout/checkout.component';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

    

const editorConfig = new MarkdownEditorOptions();
editorConfig.autoDownloadFontAwesome = true;
editorConfig.initialValue = 'Hello Editor...write something amazing.';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
   
    NewCommentComponent,
    NewDocumentComponent,
    QuestionComponent,
    SingleDocumentComponent,
    EditDocumentComponent,
    TemplateComponent,
    CategoryDialogComponent,
    DocumentCheckoutComponent,
    CarouselComponent,
    ProPageComponent,
    // CheckoutComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    EditorModule,
    MarkdownEditorModule.forRoot(editorConfig),
    MatDialog,
  ],
  providers: [
    AngularFireAuthGuard,
    AngularFireStorage,
    AngularFireFunctions,
    { provide: FUNCTIONS_REGION, useValue: 'europe-west1'}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "XXXX",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "^10.2.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^10.2.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.2.0",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.6.0",
    "angular-instantsearch": "^2.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.0",
    "html-to-pdfmake": "^2.1.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jspdf": "^2.1.1",
    "ng-image-slider": "^2.6.4",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.2",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^13.0.1",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^3.1.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
    "npm": "^6.14.8",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.68",
    "stripe": "^8.119.0",
    "tinymce": "^5.7.1",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.900.7",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.3",
    "@types/stripe-checkout": "^1.0.3",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.21",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.16.2",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change this line :

`import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';`

with:

`import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';`

also change it in your imports :)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I can't beleive this was this easy !!
I only changed it in my app.module because I need the open property but it's working perfectly now !

Comment: My pleasure :)  You can replicate this for all mat modules

Comment: dialog.open doesn't work with this change.

Comment: this is a bit insane as my IDE always remind me with MatComponents without Module. The lesson is to double check your imports

Comment: @VijayBalkawade did you find any work around for dialog.open? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem was solved by installing npm packages trough Docker, command is:

```
docker exec -it [name of your container] bash
```

if bash doesn't work, you can use just sh.
After that I installed them just by running standard

```
npm i [name of package]
```

trough command prompt.